# to get properties of a residue from pdb file

Tags: python, biopython, chemistry, pybel

I have a pdb file and I want to parse the pdb using python and I want to find the following for residues in pdb:

```
1. hydrophobicity
2. interface topology
3. solvent accessible surface area
```

I have tried using pybel

```
file_name = "4hhb.pdb"
allmols = [mol for mol in pybel.readfile("pdb", file_name)]
for mol in allmols:
    dir(mols)
```

but, I am only able to see few properties.

```
'addh', 'atoms', 'calcdesc', 'calcfp', 'charge', 'conformers', 'data', 'dim', 'draw', 'energy', 'exactmass', 'formula', 'localopt', 'make3D', 'molwt', 'removeh', 'spin', 'sssr', 'title', 'unitcell', 'write
```

How can I find these 3 properties from pdb? I can use any module available in python to get these properties.

Comment: An example `pdb` file would help.

Comment: @senshin : any pdb file from http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/home/home.do will do for example : http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=pdb&compression=NO&structureId=2INS

Answer (score 3):

Hidrophobicity (for each AA) can be found in:

`Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParamData.kd`

```
kd = {'A': 1.8, 'R':-4.5, 'N':-3.5, 'D':-3.5, 'C': 2.5, 
      'Q':-3.5, 'E':-3.5, 'G':-0.4, 'H':-3.2, 'I': 4.5, 
      'L': 3.8, 'K':-3.9, 'M': 1.9, 'F': 2.8, 'P':-1.6, 
      'S':-0.8, 'T':-0.7, 'W':-0.9, 'Y':-1.3, 'V': 4.2 }
```

I guess you have to add all the aminoacid values and get the overall hidrophobicity.

http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParamData-pysrc.html

---

You can use GROMACs (http://manual.gromacs.org/programs/gmx-sasa.html) to get the other two parameters. Viewing the C source code (https://github.com/gromacs/gromacs/blob/master/src/gromacs/trajectoryanalysis/modules/sasa.cpp), those parameters are far from obvious calculations.

I would wrap `gmx_sasa` with a `subprocess.Popen()` and get the results.

Comment: but these are atoms, I need to get properties for residues.

Comment: I understand residue=aminoacid (the `kd` dict above). E.g. aminoacid/residue "alanine (A)" have a hidrophobicity of 1.8.

I understand atom=atom. E.g. Carbon, Oxygen, Hydrogen or Nitrogen.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this[1](http://www.biostars.org/p/62967/) answer, BioPython[2](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) provides support for parsing `.pdb` files

Comment: I have seen those but they doesnt provide these 3 properties

Comment: Surely they would be extendable?

Comment: can you show any example or tutorial to find those using python?